# crystal reports attempted to read or write protected memory this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: crystal-reports

I face this error in C# Desktop Application when printing crystal report

```
crystal reports attempted to read or write protected memory this is often an indication that other memory is corrupt
```

I use VS 2013 and .NetFramework 4.0

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you think the code you use would be of any help? Maybe run it on another computer since yours has memory corruption?

Comment: I uninstall reporting service and install it again the problem is solved but when I restart the computer it returns again

Comment: What about doing it on another computer, since the message you get points to an OS/ hardware issue?

Comment: gives me the same problem sir
I read a lot of same problem , but didn't find a solution

Comment: I know nothing about Crystal-reports. However I can suggest you improve your question with the above elements in comment: 1. you solve it temporarily by uninstall/install; 2. you get the same on other hardware; 3. you found other sources relating the same -- all this and related sources should appear in the question, not in comment.